# Ashes I'll sweep if sweep I must

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Ashes to ashes and dust to dust:
>
> Ashes I'll sweep if sweep I must.
>
> I've gored a gourd and found some mice
>
> In hopes that my wishes will end in rice.
>
> The clock tick tocks, the time is near
>
> When all my dreams shall disappear.
>
> Who am I? There is one answer true;
>
> Answer fits clue as a foot in a shoe.

(I know this is probably too easy, but the first two lines came to me and I couldn't resist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> CINDERELLA?

*Ashes to ashes and dust to dust:*

*Ashes I'll sweep if sweep I must.*

> Cinderella originally lived by the fireplace and was treated like a servant, sweeping ashes for the ugly sisters (hence the "cinder" in her name).

*I've gored a gourd and found some mice*

> The pumpkin coach and mice turned into horses to pull it.

*In hopes that my wishes will end in rice.*

> Rice is traditionally thrown at weddings, and Cinderella was hoping to get married. (Thanks to the OP for clarifying this clue.)

*The clock tick tocks, the time is near*

*When all my dreams shall disappear.*

> She can only stay at the ball until midnight, when all her magical wonders disappear.

*Who am I? There is one answer true;*

*Answer fits clue as a foot in a shoe.*

> The prince discovers her because her foot fits perfectly the shoe she left behind.

---

**Feedback section**

This *was* an easy riddle, as you thought (as evidenced by the answer posted less than 2 minutes after the riddle), but not *too* easy. It was the last line that put me on to the solution; the first two lines made me think of a brush, and I didn't immediately connect the dots between the other lines, but the "foot in a shoe" bit was obviously significant and made the solution pop into my head.

Comment: yes! The rice part may have been a bit of a stretch, but the idea was that rice is traditionally thrown at weddings. She went to the ball in hopes of marrying the prince, hence, 'ending in rice' Perhaps I should change it to 'ends with rice' instead.

Comment: I agree that it was *very* easy — I got it immediately as I read it, even before I saw the last line.  Do we have a definition for “*too* easy”?